# Javascript keyup shiftKey not expected behavior

Tags: javascript

Sample of code http://jsfiddle.net/rigaconnect/3Mcxv/6/

Here is javascript with following behavior: in input field I enter some value; then press and hold ctrlKey and with mouse click below input field; value from above input field is copied below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").on('click', function(e) {
        var name1 = $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').find('input').val();
        if(e.ctrlKey) $(this).val(name1).trigger('change');
    });
});
```

In the same way I want: if I hold shiftKey and press bottom arrow button, then value from current input field is displayed in input field just below.
Here is code I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").keyup(function(e) {
        var name1 = $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').find('input').val();
        if(e.shiftKey) $(this).val(name1).trigger('change');
    });
});
```

However if I enter some value in input field, then hold shiftKey and press bottom arrow button, value disappears from current input field. I need that value remains in current input field and additionally the same value appears in input field just below.

I suppose it is because `prev().find` It finds previous that is blank. What would be correct code to find current? I changed to `$(this).find` but not working....

Comment: have you tried using firebug in frefox and looking at the console for errors?

Comment: have not tried... I suppose there is not expected behavior; I mean script works but does not do what I want; Need to change something; do not understand what.

Comment: please try; using firebug or any other debugger in JS is a must

Comment: I placed code here http://jsfiddle.net/rigaconnect/3Mcxv/6/ In first input field type something, then press bottom arrow, then hold shift and again press bottom arrow; But does not work as expected if in first input field type something, then hold shift key, press bottom arrow.

Comment: I encourage you to not to chain that much. If you make this like 5 liners function it would be... readable and easier to test via console.log();.

Comment: Beware of the e.ctrlKey thou, jQuery/jQuery.UI + MAC + e.ctrlKey = kaboom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something like the functionality you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/xQxGa/11/  // updated

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isShiftPressed = false,
        shiftCode = 16,        //    shift key code
        downArrowCode = 40,    //    down arrow key code
        $table = $('table'),
        $inputs = $('input',$table);

    $table
    .delegate('input', 'keydown', function(e) {

        if(e.which===shiftCode){
            //    shift was pressed
            isShiftPressed = true;   
        } else if(isShiftPressed && e.which===downArrowCode){
            //    shift and down arrow were pressed
            var newVal = this.value,
                i = $inputs.index(this),
                next = $inputs.eq(i+1);

            if(next){
                // move value and focus to the next
                next.val(newVal)
                    .focus();
            }
        }

    })
    .delegate('input', 'keyup', function(e) {
        //    no key pressed anymore
        isShiftPressed = false;
    });

});
```

Try to see the examples in the jQuery page.

Comment: Yes, it is something like this, but not exactly. User enters smth in input field, then press-hold `shift` and press bottom arrow key. Cursor moves one field below and in the field paste value from above field. Like here http://jsfiddle.net/rigaconnect/xQxGa/7/ but when user moves from the 2nd field to the 3rd, nothing is copied.

Comment: So, you want also the cursor to move to the 2nd field when something is copied there. But you also want this functionality only from the 1st to the 2nd input field. Not from the 2nd to 3rd, right?

Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/xQxGa/8/

Comment: Yes, I want the cursor to move to the 2nd field. And also want to move to all other fields (3rd, etc. if there are more fields).

Comment: By the way. Here is modification http://jsfiddle.net/rigaconnect/xQxGa/14/ with multiple columns. If hold SHIFT and press bottom arrow, cursor goes and value is copied to right input field. But expected cursor go to the field just below and value copied to the field just below.

Comment: Depends on how you select 'next' in line 17.
If you know for example that you have 3 input fields in every line, just do next = $inputs.eq(i + 3); ( http://jsfiddle.net/xQxGa/15/ ). This is not a good practice though, you should find a better way to identify the rows and the input fields in your code. You know better what you need though.

Comment: OK. Thanks for advice. Will experiment.